# How can I add a space between text and labels in php design?

Tags: css

I want to separate text boxes and labels and to make them all in the same width to get better look.

[image]

Comment: can you please share some code you have written?

Comment: Nothing to do with php. Take a look at HTML and CSS.

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with the layout of the page, it is an HTML/CSS problem. Please describe your problem clearer, add some code and show what you've tried.

Comment: Use CSS to fix the widths and margins.

Comment: Oh .. yes
it's css not php 
thx

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen here is the code
<style>
.txt {
  background: #ffffff;
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #ffffff);
  -webkit-border-radius: 11;
  -moz-border-radius: 11;
  border-radius: 11px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #2600ff;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0px 1px 3px #2600ff;

Comment: give some width to `label`.

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen it works
but all labels & txts gone to right
I wanna them in the center
that can be edited from devs or labels proprieties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not a PHP question at first, The presentation can be done by simple css.

here is the code:

```css
label {
        width:80px;
        clear:left;
        text-align:right;
        padding-right:12px;
    }

    input, label {
        float:left;
    }
```

```html
<label>Name:</label>
<input placeholder="Enter Name here..."><br/>
<label>Place:</label>
<input placeholder="Enter Place here..."><br/>
<label>Country:</label>
<input  placeholder="Enter Country Here..."><br/>
```

Comment: Yes, it is. The whole thing is about proper CSS property assignment to the HTML.